# Definite integration = exerise solution with substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate the following:

$$ \int_0^\infty y^2 \frac{y}{\theta} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2\theta}} dy $$

Then

$$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^3}{\theta} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2\theta}} dy $$

I tried the u-sibsitution also also integration bz parts but cannot get to the right solution.

Our professor provided us with solution in terms of x:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} x^2 \frac{x}{\theta} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}} = -\int_0^{\infty} x^2 de ^{\frac{x^2}{2\theta}} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\theta}} dx^2$$

Taking substitution: $ u=\frac{x^2}{2\theta}$

$$ 2\theta \int_0^{\infty}e^{-u} = 2\theta $$

QUESTIONS:

Where does the de come from in the second steo? What does it mean?
I would very much appriciate a detailed breakdown of the steps/operations. I have only recently started  working with integrations.

Comment: Your professor meant $$\frac{d}{dx} (e^{x^{2}/2 \theta}) = \frac{x}{\theta} e^{x^{2}/2 \theta} \implies d(e^{x^{2}/2 \theta}) = \frac{x}{\theta} e^{x^{2}/2 \theta} dx$$ This notation it is used quite frequently in mathematics, though I personally don't use it. Also, I'm not sure why the integral in $y$ has an $s$ in the numerator of the power of the exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty y^2 \frac{y}{\theta} e^{\frac{-y^2}{s\theta}} dy
&= \int_0^\infty y^2 \left(\frac{y}{\theta} e^{\frac{-y^2}{s\theta}}\right) dy \\
&= \int_0^\infty y^2 \left(\frac{s}{-2}\cdot\frac{-2y}{s\theta} e^{\frac{-y^2}{s\theta}}\right) dy \\
&= -\frac{s}{2}\int_0^\infty y^2 \cdot \frac{d}{dy}\left( e^{\frac{-y^2}{s\theta}}\right) dy \\
&= -\frac{s}{2}\int_1^0 y^2  d\left( e^{\frac{-y^2}{s\theta}}\right) \\
&= -\frac{s}{2}\int_1^0 y^2  du, \quad u=e^{\frac{-y^2}{s\theta}}\Rightarrow y^2=-s\theta\ln u \\
&= -\frac{s}{2}\int_1^0  -s\theta\ln u \, du \\
&= \frac{s^2}{\theta}\int_1^0  \ln u \, du \\
&= \frac{s^2}{\theta}\left[\left[u\ln u\right]_1^0-\int_1^0  u\cdot\frac1u \, du\right] \\
&= \frac{s^2}{\theta}\left[(0-0)+\left[u\right]_0^1\right] \\
&= \frac{s^2}{\theta}
\end{align}

Comment: I appologize i just noticed i made a mistake when typing the exercises. There is no $s$, it was supposed to be a 2, So then: $$ \int_0^{\infty} y^2 (\frac{y}{\theta}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2\theta}})dy$$. Thank you for the elaborate answer.